How to place zeroes before the quotient with \opidiv
I would like to explain how works the underlying transducer of the elementary school division. For the transducer, I need the following algorithm:

dividendbridge takes one digit (and quotient output 0)
then two digits (and quotient output another 0).

How to place two zeroes before the quotient using \xlop (in the following example 385 should become 00385)
A MWE is
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xlop}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    \begin{document} 
    \tikzmark{mydiv}\opidiv[dividendbridge, columnwidth=1.1em]{11945}{31}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}


With matrix
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (magic) [  
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
    ]
    {
        1 & 1 & 9 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 1             \\
        1 & 1 &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 3 & 8 & 5 \\
        1 & 1 & 9 &   &   \\
        & 2 & 6 & 4 &   \\
        &   & 1 & 6 & 5 \\
        &   &   & 1 & 0 \\
    };

    \draw(magic-1-5.north east) -- (magic-6-5.south east);
    \draw(magic-2-6.north west) -- (magic-2-10.north east);
    \draw(magic-1-1.north west)++(0,-2pt) --++(0,2pt) -- (magic-1-1.north east) --++(0,-2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


With xlop A solution that is far from optimal. I use resultstyle.3 to place 00.
    \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
        \usepackage{xlop}

        \begin{document} 
        \opidiv[dividendbridge, columnwidth=1.1em]{11945}{31}

        \opidiv[%
            % displayintermediary=all,
            % voperation=top,
            columnwidth=2em,
            resultstyle.3=\hspace{0.5em}0\hspace{1em}0\hspace{1em},
            % resultstyle=\hspace{3em}
            resultstyle.2=\hspace{2.5em},
            resultstyle.1=\hspace{1em}
            ]
            {11945}{31}
        \end{document}


Thank you for your quick answer (+1). How about the bridge ?

we can put dividendbridge back in the options

I did this already (and it is in your solution, in fact), but it seems in conflict with the settings and gives a poor image (or maybe I am not enough trained with \opidiv).

I post a new answer with the library matrix

Oh thank you, the solution with xlop  is exactly what I needed, I accept your answer then. –
